# Please show me a basis for $\{x | x = (x_1, x_2, \cdots, ), x_i \in \mathbb{R}\}$. Does a basis really exists?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $S = \{x | x = (x_1, x_2, \cdots, ), x_i \in \mathbb{R}\}$.
Then, $S$ is a vector space under component-wise addition and scalar multiplication.

I heard that $S$ has a basis.

I tried to find a basis for $S$, but I was not able to find a basis.
I wondered there is no basis for $S$.
To tell the truth, I was not able to find even a spanning set of $S$.

For example, $\{(1, 0, \cdots,), (0, 1, \cdots, ), \cdots\}$ is not a basis.

Please show me a basis for $S$.

Comment: $S$ has a basis **if** you assume the axiom of choice (or at least a weakened version thereof).

Comment: @Peter that is a "Schauder basis", which is not a basis in the sense of (non-topological) vector spaces.  That is, it is not a Hamel basis.

Comment: @Peter I think $(1, 1, 1, \cdots, )$ is not a finite linear combination of $(1, 0, \cdots, ), (0, 1, \cdots, ), \cdots$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A spanning set is the whole space. Every vector space has a basis. This can be proved using Zorn's Lemma. But an explicit construction of a basis may not be possible. In this case also we cannot explicitly write down a basis.

Comment: Oh really? Very surprising result. $S$ looks very simple, but we cannot explicitly write down a basis? I am very interested in this result. Thank you very much again, Kavi Rama Murthy.

Comment: I was not able to find the trivial spanning set. Thank you very much.

Comment: @tchappyha This space looks nice but it is big! Any basis for the space is uncountable. In a particular this implies that  using an inductive procedure to construct a  basis is ruled out.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

An example of a spanning set for $S$ is all of $S$ itself - that always works. But of course it is not a basis.

If you pose no restrictions on your sequences, then $S$ is not even the closure of the span of countable many sequences. This is since $l^{\infty}$ is not separable.

As you have noted, the space $S$ is a vector space and thus it has a basis. However, the theorem that any vector space has a basis uses (and is equivalent to) the axiom of choice. Hence, despite knowing that a basis exists, this basis may be very inaccessible and non-constructive.

Another example for a space which does not seem to have a well behaved basis is $C[0,1]$ the space of continuous functions on the unit interval.

Comment: Thank you very much, G. Chiusole. I am very interested in infinite dimensional vector spaces now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basis (whose construction uses the axiom of choice).

Define an equivalence relation on $S$ as follows: say that $x \sim y$ iff there exists an $N \in \Bbb N$ and $a,b \in \Bbb R$ not both zero such that $a x_n = b y_n$ for all $n > N$.

Let $\mathcal E$ denote the set of all equivalence classes over $S$ except for the equivalence class of zero.  For every $E \in \mathcal E$, we can apply the axiom of choice to select a sequence $x(E) \in E$.  Let $\mathcal B_1 = \{x(E) | E \in \mathcal E\}$.  Let $\mathcal B_2$ be the "non-basis" that you define, i.e.
$$
\mathcal B_2 = \{(1,0,0,\dots,),(0,1,0,\dots,),\dots\}.
$$
The set $\mathcal B = \mathcal B_1 \cup \mathcal B_2$ is a basis.